# Input Value Adds on to Previous Value When Changed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I am trying to make a JS/Jquery function where a user can type in a specific quantity of a product. When the user has input a number in the "Quantity" input, that number multiplies the product price and displays it in the "Sub-Total" input.

Say I have some product which is priced at `$4`, my problem is that when a user enters a quantity number, say `12` which would give a subtotal of `$48`, but then changes it to `3`, it will add `3 * $4` to the `$48` giving `$60` in the "Sub-total" input, instead of `$12`

I want it to get rid of the $48.00 and only display the new sub-total, which is $12.00. Any ideas on what I can change in my function to make this functionality possible?

My JavaScript code:

```js
function selectQuantity(qty) {

    var qtyValue = qty.value;
    var qtyId = qty.id;
    var arr = qtyId.split('_');
    var productId = 'product_' + arr[1] + '_' + arr[2];
    var productValue = $("#" + productId).val();

    var prodprice = document.getElementById("prodprice");
    var selectedValue = prodprice.options[prodprice.selectedIndex].value;

    if (selectedValue == "client") {
        $.ajax({ //create an ajax request to load_page.php
            type: "GET",
            url: "ajax_all.php?from=pos_product1&name=" + productValue,
            dataType: "html", //expect html to be returned
            success: function(response) {
                var price = response * qtyValue;
                var sub_total = $("#sub-total").val();
                $("#sub-total").val((+sub_total + +price).toFixed(2));
                gstmultiply($("#sub-total").val());
            }
        });
    } else {

        $.ajax({ //create an ajax request to load_page.php
            type: "GET",
            url: "ajax_all.php?from=pos_product&name=" + productValue,
            dataType: "html", //expect html to be returned
            success: function(response) {
                var price = response * qtyValue;
                var sub_total = $("#sub-total").val();
                $("#sub-total").val((+sub_total + +price).toFixed(2));
                gstmultiply($("#sub-total").val());
            }
        });

    }

}
```

And here is the specific component of my form:

```php
      <div class="additional_position">
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <div class="form-group clearfix">
            <div class="col-sm-1 col-sm-offset-4 type"  id="category_0">
             <select data-placeholder="Choose a Category..." onchange="selectCategory(this)"  id="category_dd_0" name="card_type[]" class="chosen-select-deselect1 form-control category" style="width:250px;">
                 <?php
                $query = mysqli_query($dbc,"SELECT DISTINCT category FROM inventory");
                echo '<option value="">Please Select</option>';
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
                    ?><option id='<?php echo $row['category'];?>' value='<?php echo $row['category'];?>'><?php echo $row['category'];?></option><?php
                }
                ?>
            </select>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-3 eq" id="product_0" style="width:250px; position:relative; left:160px;">
                <select data-placeholder="Choose a Product..." name="product_name[]" id="product_dd_0"  class="chosen-select-deselect1 form-control product" width="380" style="width:250px; position:relative;">
                    <option value=""></option>

                </select>
            </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3 qt" id="qty_0" style="width:50px; position:relative; left:180px">
                    <input data-placeholder="Choose a Product..." name="quantity_number[]" id="qty_dd_0" width="50px" onchange="selectQuantity(this);" value="0" style=" width:50px;" type="text" class="form-control quantity" />
                </div>

        </div>

    </div>



    <div id="add_here_new_position"></div>

    <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-4 triple-gap-bottom">
        <button id="add_position_button" class="btn brand-btn mobile-block">Add</button>
    </div>



      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="site_name" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Sub-Total:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <input name="sub-total" id="sub-total" value=0 type="text" class="form-control" />
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Could you create a codepen.io showing the error?

Comment: What is the difference inbetween those two ajax calls? They appear to be identical.

Comment: You can't just add in the price of the current item. You need to zero out the total and add up all the items to calculate the total from scratch.

Comment: You aren't removing the old value in either of these two lines (which get repeated twice); `var sub_total = $("#sub-total").val();`, `$("#sub-total").val((+sub_total + +price).toFixed(2));`, you probably need to recalculate the total from the items rather than just adding to the old value